# Authenticating users from separate devices to be be able to pull data from an API

Tags: authentication, api-design

I'm having trouble deciding on / understanding which method of authentication would be best in the following situation:

I have 3 separate "clients". A website, mobile app and browser extension.

Users information and data is stored in a database.

The 3 clients will access the data via an API.

What I am trying to get my head around is how users of the system would login via one of the three clients and authenticate with the API so they can then proceed to get and post data to the API.

I do not require 3rd party applications to access the API. Users can only access it by logging into the clients I provide. For this reason am I right in thinking that OAuth1/2 would be over kill?

I have attached an image which details how I envision the system.

An additional question:

Where is it in the system the authentication comes in? Would I authenticate within the API? So the user uses a form on one of the three clients to send a password. The API then returns a **"what"** if they provide valid credentials?

[image: System]

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to just use Basic Auth?

Comment: I should have added this to my post, and I will. Where is it in the system the authentication comes in?

Would I authenticate within the API? So the user uses a form on one of the three clients to send a password. The api then returns a "what" if they provide valid credentials?

Comment: Are the *users* logging in, or are the *clients* logging in? Do users have an account in your system, or only on the client?

Comment: Users will have an account on the system. They will be stored in the database.

Comment: Ok, so this is the problem OAuth is designed to solve. It lets your clients authenticate users to your service without you giving them read access to your DB or giving them your users' credentials. You should give OAuth another look. There are libraries for most of the popular languages, which should help your implementation.